Unable to install mysql-python in ananconda due to multiple errors
Hello I am trying to install 'pip install MySQL-python' through Ananachona but I keep getting multiple error and am not sure what went wrong or how to resolve i. Can anyone help me fix this?
(base) C:\Users\tnu20>pip install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Building wheel for MySQL-python (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [57 lines of output]
      C:\Users\tnu20\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:452: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'distribution-name' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'distribution_name' instead.

              This deprecation is overdue, please update your project and remove deprecated
              calls to avoid build errors in the future.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      C:\Users\tnu20\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:452: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'build-requires' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'build_requires' instead.

              This deprecation is overdue, please update your project and remove deprecated
              calls to avoid build errors in the future.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\MySQLdb\constants
      running build_ext
      building '_mysql' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IC:\Users\tnu20\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\tnu20\anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
      _mysql.c
      _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
  Running setup.py clean for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (MySQL-python)


is it really this that you want? Quote: MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.4 through 2.7 are currently supported. Python-3.0 will be supported in a future release. PyPy is supported. - it was last updated in 2014

If you want to connect to a mysql database, try conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python, see the anaconda examples

@FlyingTeller I ve tried that but get a similar error '└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires└─ python 3.11.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.'
